# jGuru RMI example don't compile

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to run jGuru examples of RMI from the tutorial at (http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html) but they didn't compile in the command line, so I can't run rmic and advance the tutorial:

```
$javac Calculator.java

$javac CalculatorImpl.java
CalculatorImpl.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Calculator
    implements Calculator {
               ^
1 error
```

both classes are exactly like they're in the jguru tutorial:
**Interface:**

```
public interface Calculator
        extends java.rmi.Remote {

    public long add(long a, long b)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException;

    public long sub(long a, long b)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException;

    public long mul(long a, long b)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException;

    public long div(long a, long b)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class CalculatorImpl
    extends
      java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject
    implements Calculator {

    // Implementations must have an
    //explicit constructor
    // in order to declare the
    //RemoteException exception
    public CalculatorImpl()
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public long add(long a, long b)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return a + b;
    }

    public long sub(long a, long b)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return a - b;
    }

    public long mul(long a, long b)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return a * b;
    }

    public long div(long a, long b)
        throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Environment vars:
(@Windows XP)

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\;...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly forgot to import your interface. You should check that.

---

For example, this is the compilation error given if the `Lol` class isn't imported :

```
Test.java:3: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : class Lol  
location: class Test  
         static Lol l;  
                ^
```

Comment: well I thought that it was not needed since they're in the same directory (and belongs to the same package <default package>)

Comment: So I've imported "import Calculator;" and gives me 2 errors: CalculatorImpl.java:1: '.' expected
import Calculator;
                 ^
CalculatorImpl.java:1: ';' expected
import Calculator;
                  ^
2 errors

Comment: Hum, I thought you removed the `package` statement. Your code runs fine on my computer, without `package` (and `import`). But the two java files need to be in the same folder.

Comment: and they are on the same folder. I guess thats something wrong w/ this jdk, I'll try to test it in other pc. Thanks for your help Colin.

Comment: It is practically certain that the problem is in your code or directory layout, not the JDK.